# Função click e bloquear inputs

Tags: html, angular

Bom dia!! Venho mais uma vez tirar duvidas... Preciso saber como eu faço para ao clicar em um botão, ele seja capaz de bloquear(disabled) todos os inputs ou selects que eu desejar, basicamente, talvez o *ngIf possa fazer isso, mas não sei como ainda... 
Segue o código do botão e do select:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <label>Forma de Pagamento:</label>
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="forma">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let pgmtt of pgmt" value="{{pgmtt.Codigo}}">{{pgmtt.Codigo}} - {{pgmtt.Nome}}</option>
   </select>
</div>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 <!-- botão -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" >Incluir
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Um simples Javascript resolve o problema!**

> Extra a função habilitar

```js
function desabilitar() {
    document.getElementById("qqId").disabled=true;
}

function habilitar() {
    document.getElementById("qqId").disabled=false;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
   <label>Forma de Pagamento:</label>
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="forma" id="qqId">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let pgmtt of pgmt" value="{{pgmtt.Codigo}}">{{pgmtt.Codigo}} - {{pgmtt.Nome}}</option>
   </select>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="desabilitar()">Desabilitar
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
 </button>
 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="habilitar()">Habilitar
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
 </button>
```

> Para essse simples código vale ressaltar que o uso de javascript puro tem vantagem sobre jQuery que acarreta perda de performance.
>
> Algumas vezes, tudo que você quer é apenas um recurso da biblioteca, mas ao invés disso, você tem várias prateleiras pela frente e acaba perdendo um certo tempo procurando o que realmente quer.

**Para desabilitar ao clicar no select**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(document).on('click', '.form-control',function() {
       $(".form-control").prop("disabled", true);
    });    
                     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <label>Forma de Pagamento:</label>
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="forma">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let pgmtt of pgmt" value="{{pgmtt.Codigo}}">{{pgmtt.Codigo}} - {{pgmtt.Nome}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom!! Tenho mais uma duvida, será que ao clicar no select, isso também é possível?

Comment: @BrunoMiqueas, qual seria a utilidade disso?

Comment: É mais por curiosidade mesmo, a minha dúvida principal já foi tirada xD

Answer (score 2):

**Pensa em criar uma função em javascript para determinar o que o btn tem que fazer**

```
$("#btnteste").click(function()
 {
   $("#id").val("#id").prop( "disabled", true );
 }
```

Comment: eu tentei dessa maneira, porém ele não desabilitou o select após o click

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode fazer usando uma *classe*. Eu dei o nome de `.erro`, ai quando vc clica no `btn` todos os campos que tiverem a classe **.erro** ficam desabilitados

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").on("click", function() {
        $(".erro").prop("disabled", true);
    })
});
```

```html
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label>Forma de Pagamento:</label>
  <select class="form-control erro" formControlName="forma">
     <option selected>Selecione...</option>
     <option *ngFor="let pgmtt of pgmt" value="{{pgmtt.Codigo}}">{{pgmtt.Codigo}} - {{pgmtt.Nome}}</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="erro">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="erro"></textarea>
</div>

<!-- botão -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" >Incluir
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</button>
```